# Why I'm getting a 403 (Insufficient Permission) error on Google Workspace Admin SDK?

Tags: google-oauth, google-workspace, google-admin-sdk

When I try to access Admin SDK API I get this error:

```
XHRGEThttps://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?customer=some_custumer
[HTTP/3 403 Forbidden 220ms]
```

Even passing a API_KEY (&key=my_api_key), the same happens.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Insufficient Permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "ccc.hosted.frontend.directory.v1.DirectoryUsers.List",
          "service": "admin.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Header:

```
    www-authenticate
        Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error="insufficient_scope", scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user https://www.googleapis.com/auth/directory.user https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.directory.user.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/directory.user.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
```

I've configured my app on Google Console. Configured the authentication and scopes [like this scopes](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list). I've also configured domain-wide-delegation in Admin Console. I'm expecting to list all Workspace users through this API, but I got this error.

The OAuth works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are using but here you have my assumptions:

1. If you are using OAuth, you will need to use a user with enough
   privileges to list your users (a super admin account for example)
2. If you are using a service account, besides allowing wide domain
   delegation you need to implement impersonation in your code, that
   way you will specify which account the service account will
   impersonate to make the API call. So, it is very important to
   impersonate an account with enough permissions

If you have any questions please let me know